# The buttons of program aren't working. Why?

Tags: android, button

I am reading Hello Android book and I am writing the code from the book in eclipse but the buttons not working. Why is that?

Sudoku/src/org.example.sudoku/Sudoku.java

```
package org.example.sudoku;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Sudoku extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private static final String TAG = "Sudoku";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up click listeners for all the buttons
    View continueButton = findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
    continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View newButton = findViewById(R.id.new_button);
    newButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View aboutButton = findViewById(R.id.about_button);
    aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
    exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
 }



 // ...
 public void onClick(View v) {
     switch (v.getId()) {
     case R.id.about_button:
         Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
         startActivity(i);
         break;
     // More buttons go here (if any) ...

     }
  }
}
```

Sudoku/src/org.example.sudoku/About.java

```
package org.example.sudoku;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class About extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.about);
}
 }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.example.sudoku"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
             android:name=".MainActivity"
             android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
             <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".About"
            android:label="@string/about_label">     
        </activity>            

    </application>

 </manifest>
```

I click in About button, but not working and not run activity. if you need another files of program, tell me.
Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a `MainActivity` class?  Your manifest says to start `MainActivity` initially.  Perhaps you meant to put your Sudoku Activity in the manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. **In Manifest file you write MainActivity please change it to Sudoku.**

For this error cannot convert from View to Button

You need to cast the view to Button:

```
Button aboutButton  = (Button)findViewById(android.R.id.aboutButton );
```

Comment: May I Know the Reason for Down Vote Please ?

Comment: Button is itself a View, so what is the problem if the OP is setting click event for View?

Comment: Thank you. I add it and import android.widget.Button; to Sudoku.java and the program has error:Type mismatch: cannot convert from View to Button.

Comment: the error is---> Type mismatch: cannot convert from View to Button.

Comment: I change MainActivity in Manifest to Sudoku and the program is run. Thank you for help :)

Comment: @LalitPoptani, Now what you tell about this error ? cannot convert from View to Button.

Comment: one question: why should i changed MainActivity to Sudoku in Manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the Button class specific:

```
Button aboutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.about_button);
aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all Change All View to Button as

```
Button continueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
```

**AND SECOND  Take context of activity in click event as**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
     switch (v.getId()) {
     case R.id.about_button:
         Intent i = new Intent(Sudoku.this, About.class);
    /////////       change here ^^^^^^^^^^^     
         startActivity(i);
         break;
     // More buttons go here (if any) ...

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the activity_main.xml file, you should declare your button,

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/about_button"
    android:layout_width="319dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="About" />
```

Then in your class, sudoku.java,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up click listeners for all the buttons

    Button aboutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.about_button);
    aboutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                            //Code for whatever you want to perform on this button click
                        }
 }
```